# Searching from right to left and diagonally in a word search - Java

Tags: java, arrays

I have a program that is supposed to search for 'ruby', 'python', and 'java' in a word search puzzle. My professor gave me the code to search left to right but I am unsure how to go from right to left and diagonally. I've seen other people code the same problem, but I think my professor wants me to do it in a similar method that she has done it.

I've attempted to go from right to left but I either get an Out of Bounds exception or the search comes back negative.

```
public static void main (String[] argv)
{
    char[][] puzzle = {
        {'n', 'o', 'h', 't', 'y', 'p', 's'},
        {'m', 'i', 'a', 'r', 'y', 'c', 'c'},
        {'l', 'l', 'e', 'k', 's', 'a', 'h'},
        {'r', 'u', 'b', 'y', 'v', 'm', 'e'},
        {'e', 'h', 'h', 'a', 'l', 'l', 'm'},
        {'p', 'c', 'j', 'n', 'i', 'c', 'e'},
        {'r', 'e', 'e', 'k', 'b', 'i', 'p'}
    };

    String result1 = findWordLefttoRight (puzzle, "ruby");
    String result2 = findWordRighttoLeft (puzzle, "python");
    //String result3 = findWordBottomLefttoTopRight (puzzle, "java");
    System.out.println (result1);
    System.out.println (result2);
    //System.out.println (result3);
}

/*Given by Professor*/

static String findWordLefttoRight (char[][] puzzle, String word)
{
// First convert the String into a char array.
char[] letters = word.toCharArray ();

// Now try every possible starting point in the puzzle array.
for (int i=0; i<puzzle.length; i++) {
    for (int j=0; j<puzzle[i].length; j++) {

    // Use (i,j) as the starting point.
    boolean found = true;

    // Try to find the given word's letters.
    for (int k=0; k<letters.length; k++) {
        if ( (j+k >= puzzle[i].length) || (letters[k] != puzzle[i][j+k]) ) {
        // Not a match.
        found = false;
        break;
        }
    }

    // If we went the whole length of the word, we found it.
    if (found) {
        return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" +j;
    }

    }
}

return "String " + word + " not found";
}

/* My attempt at going from right to left */

static String findWordRighttoLeft (char[][] puzzle, String word)
{
// First convert the String into a char array.
char[] letters = word.toCharArray ();

// Now try every possible starting point in the puzzle array.
for (int i=puzzle.length; i>0; i--) {
    for (int j=puzzle.length; j>0; j--) {

    // Use (i,j) as the starting point.
    boolean found = true;

    // Try to find the given word's letters.
    for (int k=0; k<letters.length; k++) {          
        if ( (j+k <= puzzle.length) || (letters[k] == puzzle[i][j+k]) ) { 
        // Not a match.
        found = false;
        break;
        }
    }

    // If we went the whole length of the word, we found it.
    if (found) {
        return "String " + word + " found in row=" + i + " col=" +j;
    }

    }
}

return "String " + word + " not found";
}
```

Comment: So, what's the question?

Comment: To search right to left diagonally.

Comment: Problem number 1: array indexes are numbered from 0 to length-1. So, for (int j=puzzle.length; j>0; j--) should be for (int j=puzzle.length-1; j>=0; j--). There could be other problems, but you need to formulate a question with specific problem rather than to ask to fix your code.

Comment: Please note that even your professor's algorithm is rather inefficient. You don't have to go to the end of a row of the array to find out that there is no more room for the word having, let's say, 5 characters. If your word has five characters and the row has nine, then you have to search up to position four, for the word has to end at position eight if there is a match.

Answer (score 0):

Write out your puzzle matrix on a piece of paper (grid paper if you have it), and put indexes for each row and column on the sizes of the matrix.   Look at the nested for loop you are using to search the matrix from left to right, which starts with comment `//Now try every possible starting point in the puzzle array`, and understand how it works to search the matrix you have on paper.    Then look at how you would search from right to left and decide how you would change the code to traverse the matrix from right to left.   Once you've solved that, do same thing for diagonally.  Remember that diagonally has four cases:

1. Upper left to lower right
2. Lower left to upper right
3. Upper right to lower left
4. Lower right to upper left

For English readers, it's probably more intuitive to do diagonally as case #1, so start with that first so your understanding of the problem grows.

For OutOfBounds errors, add debug statements in the code (or even better, learn to use your IDE debugger) so you can understand how the for loop is working, and where it is going too far.

Answer (score 0):

the below condition will cause out of bound exception

```
(letters[k] != puzzle[i][j+k])
```

where

```
J max value can be puzzle[i].length  and
k max value can be letters.length
```

since you were adding them both and checking that index it is causing the exception. The max value can only be puzzle[i].length

**Note:** findWordLefttoRight logic is also not correct, same issue exsist. it will also cause out of bound exception